# Exception errors when closing server

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.3

I'm fairly new to django and have been following the tutorial/documentation, got to the point where I am supposed to set up the server. I am using Ubuntu and have mysql 5.5 server installed with python3.4, pip etc. So I went through the steps of setting up the database and server using mysql-connector-python, I added the south app as well to django settings and everything works, I can run the server, view the django congrats page, but the trouble is when I close the server in the terminal, ctrl C, an Error gets thrown.

```
Exception ResourceWarning: ResourceWarning('unclosed <socket.socket object, fd=9, family=2,    type=1, proto=6>',) in <socket.socket object, fd=9, family=2, type=1, proto=6> ignored
```

Not sure where to fix the problem. Do I have the write close connection somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the same messages but I don't care because probably I can do nothing.
I think this connections are opened by Django and Django should do something with this, not me.
But normally servers work all the time without stops and maybe nobody cares about unclosed socket.

Comment: I get the same error and i will continue to search because, this a flaw, and it can become desastrous. A simple ddos is can really be effective in this case, since an open socket = memory !